# Comparing a Decimal within a Number Range

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, textbox, decimal

ok I am running into a problem. I have a decimal in a textbox that I am trying to Range between a set number. As you can see in the picture I have a value that is in the Full Scale, which updates the value on the CalCert with the decimal 2.9995 mV/V.

The issue here is the  decimal value has to be plus/minus 30 of 3 mV. example. `2.9970 - 3.0030` that is the range. Anything outside the range I am needing it to trigger a warning dialog. My code that I was going to use I am not sure why its not working.

I am using if statements but the only error is in the ("3.0031") section.

```
            double value = 0;
            if (double.TryParse(TxtFullScale.Text, out value))
            {
                value /= 10000;
            }

            TxtCalFullScale.Text = string.Format("{0:#.0000}", value) + "  " + "mV/V";

            if (TxtFullScale.Text >= TxtFullScale.Text.ToString("3.0031"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Full Scale value is in a non conformence state.");
            }
            else if (TxtFullScale.Text <= TxtFullScale.Text.ToString("2.9970"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Full Scale value is in a non conformence state.");
            }
```

I can take and make the code work with to a point with

```
           if (TxtFullScale.Text == "3.0031")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Full Scale value is in a non conformence state.");
            }
            else if (TxtFullScale.Text =="2.9970")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Full Scale value is in a non conformence state.");
            }
```

However if the range is put in the text as `3.0032` then it never shows the messagebox. What am I missing here?

Comment: You can't apply >= to operands of type `string`. You should convert them to `double` and then you can compare values.

Comment: @mohammad: Generally, `decimal` would be a better choice than `double`; less chance of floating point weirdness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first, you can't do math operations with strings on C#

```
var a = "3";
var b = "2";
Console.WriteLine(a+b);
```

Will result in 32!

Second, this line is a bit strange

```
TxtFullScale.Text >= TxtFullScale.Text.ToString("3.0031")
```

Should be like

```
TxtFullScale.Text >= "3.0031"
```

you need to parse the number as an decimal, then compare, like this:

```
public const double LIMIT_1 = 3.0031;

public static void Main()
{
    var val = "3.0032";
    var x = double.TryParse(val, out double dec);           

    if(dec >= LIMIT_1)
      Console.WriteLine("yay");
}
```

Comment: I will try this and see if I can get it to work. I have tried different solutions of how I done it in other programs but nothing seems to work in my favor. This program is for my company I work for which is still running XP and wants to update to Win10 however the software they use is only compatible with XP. So I am updating our software by a good 20 years.

Comment: it did not work. all it does is trigger my message box on any number entered.

Comment: Can you post your solution?